# How to change the address of a channel from the ChannelFactory (WCF)

Tags: wcf

I am trying to create a smart proxy so if a call to one address doesn't work, the proxy automatically goes to the second address. To do this I am using Unity with `ChannelFactory`. I am able to intercept the calls on the Channel that I get back from `ChannelFactory.CreateChannel()`, but I am not able to tell my Channel to close and point to a new address.

I don't want to re-create the channel, I just want to re-configure it. Is it possible? I am not able to do this with `IChannel`, `ICommunicationObject` or `IClientChannel`... I can only get the address as read only but not change it.

(I know this is possible with WCF Routers, but I am trying do solve the single point of failure to the router).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have a channel, you cannot change its address later on - but when you create the channel from your factory, you can supply an endpoint address to use:

```
public TChannel CreateChannel(EndpointAddress address)
```

See the [MSDN docs for the CreateChannel method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms575251.aspx) for more details.

So you can do something like this:

```
EndpointAddress addr = new EndpointAddress("http://yourserver:7777/YourService");    
IYourService client = factory.CreateChannel(addr);
```

If you want to change it, you just need to create a new channel instance from your factory, and specify a different endpoint address.

Comment: Thanks. I agree that's the only way to do this.